# Clear Shaky in Cocos2dx

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x

I added shake to a sprite and tried to reset it after shake, but it's now working:

```
    cocos2d::CCShaky3D* shaky = cocos2d::CCShaky3D::create(3.0, true, cocos2d::ccg(64,64), 1);
    gfScene->runAction(CCSequence::create(shaky,shaky->reverse(),NULL));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's happening that's not what you want?

Comment: @godel9 After shake the screen remains distorted, but I want it to reset to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

I found I should add CCStopGrid::action() to end of sequence:

```
gfScene->runAction(CCSequence::create(shaky,shaky->reverse(),CCStopGrid::action(),NULL));
```